# Cómo saber en un condicional el ultimo registro? Postgres

Tags: postgresql

Necesito una condicional que me diga que es el ultimo registro, para hacer algo

```
FOR algo IN    
select * from tabla
LOOP
IF(si es el ultimo registro) THEN
   "hacer algo"
END IF;
END LOOP;
```

Answer (score 0):

De esta manera puedes obtener el último registro

```
SELECT MAX(columna) FROM tabla;
```

Es un placer ayudarte. Saludos!